# I am trying to fill google form using python but getting google authentication error

Tags: python, google-forms

Google authentication function:

```
def updateform(user, passwd, url, data):
    auth_handler = urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
    auth_handler.add_password(
        realm='New mail feed',
        uri='https://mail.google.com',
        user='%s@gmail.com' % user,
        passwd=passwd
    )
    opener = urllib.request.build_opener(auth_handler)
    urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
    feed = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    l = requests.post(url, data)
    return l


url="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSefpEhiDaSb2DUxyvaNkFLDWXzbq9TtJ8CmbdQpL0xHZolmRw/fromResponse"
data = {'entry.2005620554' : 'ujjal'}
updatefrom("username","password", url, data)

Output:
<Response [401]>
```

url : [Google Form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSefpEhiDaSb2DUxyvaNkFLDWXzbq9TtJ8CmbdQpL0xHZolmRw/formResponse)

I am trying to post data in google form. But I am getting 401 unauthorized error. Help !

update : It works fine with this url

```
url = 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdlveTOIECaMD1BHm2CU8qS8vbfwSEBmgtRGkP6pkeiTJosHA/formResponse'
updatefrom("username","password", url, data)

Output:
<Response [200]>
```

Url : [form url](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdlveTOIECaMD1BHm2CU8qS8vbfwSEBmgtRGkP6pkeiTJosHA/formResponse)

Comment: Cant u just use string concat using + for user?

Comment: try using the google forms REST API

Comment: @JoeFerndz more information please

Comment: okay @AkIonSight thank you

Comment: you should solve this earlier and not use %s. `user='%s@gmail.com' % user` or make it `user=user+'@gmail.com'`

Comment: sorry @JoeFerndz its not working . btw I guess both gives same result

Comment: you can find more info here. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/